# blank pdf page is created when im using itext in android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlH6m.png)
I m adding images in pdf file to generate its pdf as a document problem is this that its automatically adding 1st page as a blank page and remaining pages contain images that are fine. so how should i overcome with this problem.

```
pdfPath = dir + "/" + txtFileName.getText().toString() + ".pdf";

String pdfFileName = txtFileName.getText().toString() + ".pdf";
PdfWriter writer;
File file = new File(dir, pdfFileName);
Document document = new Document();

try {
     writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
            new FileOutputStream(file));
    HeaderFooterPageEvent event = new HeaderFooterPageEvent();
    writer.setPageEvent(event);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (DocumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
document.open();

Image image = null;

for (int i = 0; i < listofimage.size(); i++) {
    String imgFileName = listofimage.get(i).toString();
    try {

        image = Image.getInstance(imgFileName);
    } catch (BadElementException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    float scaler = ((document.getPageSize().getWidth()
            - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin()) / image
            .getWidth()) * 90;
    Log.i("Scale Percentage", scaler + "");
    image.scalePercent(scaler);

    try {

        document.newPage();
        document.add(image);
        document.addAuthor("Genetech Solutions");

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

document.close();
```

`HeaderFooterPageEvent` essentially consists of:

```
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("Generated by Snap Scanner Powered By Genetech Solutions"), 180, 30, 0);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("page " + document.getPageNumber()), 550, 30, 0);
}
```

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Please show your `HeaderFooterPageEvent`. I assume you do something wrong there, just like @Bruno in his answer does.

Comment: public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("Generated by Snap Scanner Powered By Genetech Solutions"), 180, 30, 0);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("page " + document.getPageNumber()), 550, 30, 0);
    }

Comment: when im removing HeaderFooterPageEvent its working fine. but i need to include this too

Comment: Have you tried switching lines as proposed by @Bruno?

Comment: yes tried but not working

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but could not, cf my answer. Furthermore, looking at your screenshot, your empty first page is wider than the following page which cannot happen with the code you show. Probably you tried to tidy up your code for posting here and doing so resolved your issue?

Comment: Thanks @mkl ur solution is working :)))

Comment: @YasirAhmedKhan Please accept the answer that was given my mkl to avoid confusion. I didn't see the comments to your question. I only saw mkl's answer and I didn't know the issue was resolve (Note: accepting an answer is also showing your gratitude; it's not very polite to refuse accepting a good answer).

Answer (score 1):

I burnt down your code to the following test case, removing `try-catch` constructs to keep it short and inlining the page event listener:

```
@Test
public void testYasirAhmedKhanOriginal() throws IOException, DocumentException
{
    List<String> listofimage = Collections.nCopies(3, "src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext5/layer/Willi-1.jpg");
    // Collections.singletonList("src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext5/layer/Willi-1.jpg");
    File file = new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "YasirAhmedKhanOriginal.pdf");

    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
    writer.setPageEvent(new PdfPageEventHelper()
    {
        public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("Generated by Snap Scanner Powered By Genetech Solutions"), 180, 30, 0);
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("page " + document.getPageNumber()), 550, 30, 0);
        }
    });
    document.open();

    for (int i = 0; i < listofimage.size(); i++)
    {
        String imgFileName = listofimage.get(i).toString();
        Image image = Image.getInstance(imgFileName);

        float scaler = ((document.getPageSize().getWidth() - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin()) /
                image.getWidth()) * 90;
        image.scalePercent(scaler);

        document.newPage();
        document.add(image);
        document.addAuthor("Genetech Solutions");
    }

    document.close();
}
```

*([UnwantedPage.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/UnwantedPage.java))*

The result:

[image: the result pdf]

No empty first page, everything as it should be...

Thus, either the OP does something additional which causes the empty page or he uses some old iText version which may have had some bug in this respect.

Comment: Yes @mkl, either something is wrong in `HeaderFooter` or he's using an old iText version...

Comment: Considering the OP said in a comment to his question that my code works for him, I assume there was something in his `onStartPage`.

Comment: Aha, I didn't see that comment. Usually when something works, the OP accepts the answer. I hate it when that doesn't happen. It feels so ungrateful.

Comment: Great! In that case please accept the answer (click on the tick at the upper left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `document.newPage()` you create a new page.

`document.newPage()` is ignored if the current page is blank.

I see that you introduce a `HeaderFooterPageEvent`. If you add content in this `HeaderFooterPageEvent`, then the current page isn't blank. I guess you're doing something in this event you shouldn't do.

You are also doing this in the wrong order:

```
document.newPage();
document.add(image);
```

First you add a new page, then you add an image. (It's kind of funny that you then complain that your document starts with a blank page.)

Note that adding a `newPage()` wouldn't be a problem if you didn't do something wrong in`HeaderFooterPageEvent`.

Why don't you switch these lines like this:

```
document.add(image);
document.newPage();
```

Now you're adding the image first, then you're creating a new page. This won't cause any problems if you page event is written correctly. However, we can't comment on that page event because you're not sharing the `HeaderFooterPageEvent` code.

Finally, this line is also wrong:

```
document.addAuthor("Genetech Solutions");
```

You shouldn't add metadata about the author after `document.open()`.